# Terminal Stuck: Running Flutter App on iPad - Installing and launching...

Tags: ipad, terminal, flutter, iosdeployment

When I try to run a flutter app on an iPad connected to my Mac, on the terminal the progress gets stuck here:
[image]

The app is fully open on the iPad and functional. But on the terminal, I can not hot reload/restart. Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: I had the same problem, and like Gunter said, the solution is to run `flutter doctor` and make sure that every error and warning is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
 pod repo remove master
 pod setup
```